# Online Cart Not refreshing

Tags: vb.net

basically Whenever I am adding items to the online basket it should refresh and show count of items in the basket on its own, however for some reason cart is not refreshing on its own and showing proper count, unless page is refreshed manually.. Any kind of solution is welcome. please check the site  http://grocery.egrocer.ae

```
/// <summary>
///     Update the quantity of item(s) in the shopping cart and then display the contents 
///     of the cart.
///     <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
///     <param name="e">An EventArgs that contains the event data.</param>
/// </summary>
public void UpdateButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    bool cartHasItems = false;       //Set if the cart contains items

    Cart shoppingCart = ShoppingCart(false);
    if (!shoppingCart.IsEmpty)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        //
        // Validators have run so we can assume valid input
        //

        //
        // reset the quanities for all the items in cart
        //
        DataRowCollection orderRows = shoppingCart.OrderItems.Rows;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataGridItem item in CartItemsDataGrid.Items)
        {
            //update the quantity
            orderRows[i][1] = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)item.FindControl("QuantityTextBox")).Text);
            ++i;
        }

        shoppingCart.UpdateItems();

        cartHasItems = !shoppingCart.IsEmpty;
        if (cartHasItems) 
        {
            //Bind the DataGrid to the items
            CartItemsDataGrid.DataSource = (ICollection)shoppingCart.OrderItems.DefaultView;
            CartItemsDataGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }

    //
    // Set visibility of displayed items to correspond to
    //   whether or not we have items in the cart.
    //
    ShoppingCartPanel.Visible = cartHasItems;
    CartItemsDataGrid.Visible = cartHasItems;
    CheckOutHyperLink.Visible= cartHasItems;
    EmptyCartLabel.Visible = !cartHasItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding refresh to the code after the DataGridView.DataBind.

```
/// <summary>
///     Update the quantity of item(s) in the shopping cart and then display the contents 
///     of the cart.
///     <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
///     <param name="e">An EventArgs that contains the event data.</param>
/// </summary>
public void UpdateButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool cartHasItems = false;
//Set if the cart contains items
    Cart shoppingCart__1 = ShoppingCart(false);
    if (!shoppingCart__1.IsEmpty) {
        if (!Page.IsValid) {
            return;
        }

        //
        // Validators have run so we can assume valid input
        //

        //
        // reset the quanities for all the items in cart
        //
        DataRowCollection orderRows = shoppingCart__1.OrderItems.Rows;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataGridItem item in CartItemsDataGrid.Items) {
            //update the quantity
            orderRows(i)(1) = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)item.FindControl("QuantityTextBox")).Text);
            i += 1;
        }

        shoppingCart__1.UpdateItems();

        cartHasItems = !shoppingCart__1.IsEmpty;
        if (cartHasItems) {
            //Bind the DataGrid to the items
            CartItemsDataGrid.DataSource = (ICollection)shoppingCart__1.OrderItems.DefaultView;
            CartItemsDataGrid.DataBind();
            CartItemsDataGrid.Refresh();
        }
    }

//
// Set visibility of displayed items to correspond to
//   whether or not we have items in the cart.
//
    ShoppingCartPanel.Visible = cartHasItems;
    CartItemsDataGrid.Visible = cartHasItems;
    CheckOutHyperLink.Visible = cartHasItems;
    EmptyCartLabel.Visible = !cartHasItems;
}
```